# How to add images in between array elements

Tags: arrays, image, ios7

I'm creating an array and displaying it using the componentsjoinedbyString:" | ". My code is as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *items=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"A walk to remember",@"The Last song",@"The Notebook",@"Dear John",@"The Longest Ride",nil];

for(int i=0;i<[items count];i++){

    NSString* lab=[items objectAtIndex:i];
    lab=[items componentsJoinedByString:@" | "];
    NSLog(@"label:%@",lab);
    [self.label setText:lab];

}
```

But Now I want to add an image in between the elements(instead of "|"). Which would be the best way to do it? Thank you for any help.

Comment: The for-loop seems unnecessary since lab is always set to all the items joined together (in addition, only the last label change will be "visible" since there's no chance for the UI to be updated during the loop).  By "image in between the elements", do you mean something like an emoticon or an actual UIImage/UIImageView?  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to add an icon, in between the array elements. That ll be in the image format only right? How Can I add the icons in-between instead of pipes.